# Panel inside button not working properly in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

In my application i have 3 panels corresponding anchor tags. Initially when the page is load first panel is visible rest of two panels is in disable state. when i  click second anchor tag it is not displaying once it display in that when i click button data is not display properly i need to display when i click anchor tag corresponding panel data will be display

Comment: I don't understand what's not working. I click first link, it displays `pnl1`. I click second link, it displays User Name drop down with dates drop down and a button GET. I click third link, it displays `User Details`. Is it not correct?

Comment: you've displayed what you want and you've given nice efforts as we can see. can you tell us what you're getting from what you've already done.?

Comment: when i click second link it displays data and filling the data getting the details for clicking GET button(panel inside button) it's not showing the details again when i click link it appears getting data list

Comment: So you basically wants following. if SpPw.Click -> pnlPw.Show, pnlAw.Hide, pnlUd.Hide and similarly in all other cases right.?

Answer (score 0):

Remove following part from your code.

```
   $("#<%= btnGetAct.ClientID %>").click(function () {
      $("#<%= pnlPw.ClientID %>").hide();
      $("#<%= pnlAct.ClientID %>").show();
      $("#<%= pnlUserdetails.ClientID %>").hide();               
   });
```

You are calling this `Click` from both side. From your client side as well as server side so I think it is creating conflict and because of that you're not getting your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the show/hide init of your panels in your `$(document).ready` function to prevent resetting to the initial state every time your page is loaded, for example when you're clicking your `GET` button.

You can set this initial state directly in your aspx code, setting a `display:none` to the panels you want to hide at start:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlAct" runat="server" Style="display:none;"> [...] </asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlUserdetails" runat="server" Style="display:none;"> [...] </asp:Panel>
```

Comment/remove theses lines in your JavaScript:

```
//$("#<%= pnlPw.ClientID %>").show();
//$("#<%= pnlAct.ClientID %>").hide();
//$("#<%= pnlUserdetails.ClientID %>").hide();
```

Then, your code should work properly.

Comment: Hi, @krlzx, it's not working again same problem when i click button GET it disable all the details when i click again second link it appears whatever i need details see my image above

Comment: Well, I tried to fix the display of elements problem you described. For the display of user data, it's hard to fix without any code-behind code. You should post the relevant code-behind code and explain maybe with an image, workflow what should happen with your buttons/links to better help you.